# Fix messed up ubuntu 22.04 icons

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-gnome

For some reason nautilus crashed and when it recovered by icons were messed up. See picture below.

[image]
The problem is somewhere in my config folder but I don't know which file. I can't delete my entire config folder. Can someone help with this?

Comment: I encountered similar problems in the past. In my case I had to log out of the user account and log back in to 'fix' the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "Settings", "Accessibility", you have turned on "High Contrast". Head over there again, and turn the setting off.

Comment: oooh. That was it. I didn't remember turning on high contrast. Thank you so much.